# PowerMock RandomUtils.nextLong() to return different values from my test

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I am trying to find a way to powermock RandomUtils.nextLong()

```
final Map<Long,ObjectA> objectAById = Maps.newHashMap()
for(Entry<Long,Long> entry: mapOfLongValues.entrySet()){
.....
....
long generatedId = RandomUtils.nextLong()
ObjectA a = new Object();
a.color= red;
objectAByID.put(generatedId,a);
}
```

The above is my implementation.

I am writing a Junit test to test it.

Is there a way I can powermock randomutils so that it passes me different values each time from my test to test my implementation.

I can't think of a way to return different values for my test each time for randomUtils when traversing through the map.

eg.

```
Map<Long,Long> mapofLongValues contains <1,2>,<3,4>
output : objectAById contains <randomNumberPassedFromMyTest,ObjectA>, <RandomNumberPassedFromMyTest,ObjectA>
```

I hope the question is making sense.

Comment: Not really - you say you want **random** input in your tests? And RandomUtil does not provide those? Than RandomUtil is not random at all? Or do you want "fixed" random numbers to be returned, so the tests always run the same?

Comment: @Jan: I want fixed random numbers to be returned, so the tests always run the same.

Comment: can do that as well - always set same seed.

Answer (score 0):

[`RandomUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/RandomUtils.html#JVM_RANDOM) exposes a static field `JVM_RANDOM` which is a `Random`.

You should be able to call

```
RandomUtils.JVM_RANDOM.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

in your test - effectively changing the seed (and thus the random sequence) to change in each iteration.

Not need for mocking that way.

In case of fixed numbers (test has always the same), you just initialize the seed to have *fixed* long value - then `RandomUtils` returns same sequence in every run.

```
RandomUtils.JVM_RANDOM.setSeed(123456789L);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I can't say for sure since I haven't seen your full code, but `objectAByID.put(generatedId,a);` may suggest that you're using the values as ids for some objects. While this may seem logical at first, there is no guarantee that the generated numbers will be **distinct**. Please keep this in mind because it may not be what you're looking for,

Now, strictly from the power-mock perspective, you can mock `JVMRandom` to return different but easily identifiable values on each call, which however will not be *truly random*.

```
// delegate test running to PowerMock so it can work its black magic
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

/* prepare classes for instrumentation:
 - JVMRandom for mocking because it's final
 - RandomUtils for creating new JVMRandom instances */
@PrepareForTest({RandomUtils.class, JVMRandom.class})
public class RdspSimulatorSbbLocalInterfaceTest {

    @Mock
    private JVMRandom mockedRandom;
    private long currentValue;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // reset before each test
        currentValue = 0;

        // use an answer to calculate and return a known value on each invocation
        when(mockedRandom.nextLong()).thenAnswer(invocation -> (currentValue++));

        // whenever a new JVMRandom instance is created, make sure to return our mock
        PowerMockito.whenNew(JVMRandom.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedRandom);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldMockJVMRandom() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            assertEquals(i, RandomUtils.nextLong());
        }
    }
}
```